# Sharepoint framework experience. React or Angular?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I'm somewhat confused as to what technogy to use with Sharepoint Online framework experience.  Is React/Redux the better dev option now for web parts that extend and build on sharepoint? Is Angular then better suited for the spa / provider hosted app world? Is Angular properly supported by spfx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this article may give you some directions:
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/angular-react-or-vue-which-web-framework-to-focus-on-for-spfx

The author does not choose one above the other, but gives some directions to help you choose.

I think, at Juni 2018, React is better integrated with SPFx because React is used by M$ to build many parts of SP and Office365. But there are lots of initiatives in the Angular world as well. I think it really depends on your background, current knowledge... If you already know one of React or Angular, then stick to that, else if you are new to both, then choose React.
But that is opinionated...